# How can I get recurrent items between n lists?

Tags: python

I created a dictionary that contains a word as key and list of filenames in which that word exists. Now I want to create a function that takes in a query and a dictionary and returns a simple list that refers to the filenames in which all these words exist together.

So far I made a big list that has smaller lists which represent the filenames in which these word exist but I don't know how to get the common elements between these small lists.

My code so far:

```
query = 'Dynamics Research'
queryList = query.split(" ")
print(queryList)
results = []
for word in queryList:
  if word in indexDict.keys():
    fileAndLines = indexDict[word]
  results.append(list(fileAndLines.keys()))

print(results)
```

This returns:

```
['Dynamics', 'Research']
[['./1/1129.txt', './1/1608.txt', './1/1598.txt', './1/1115.txt'],
 ['./1/1129.txt',
  './1/1541.txt',
  './1/1139.txt',
  './1/1996.txt',
  './1/1935.txt',
  './1/1963.txt',
  './1/1419.txt',
  './1/1544.txt',
  './1/1855.txt',
  './1/1064.txt',
  './1/1626.txt',
  './1/1852.txt',
  './1/1698.txt',
  './1/1183.txt',
  './1/1167.txt',
  './0/619.txt',
  './0/53.txt',
  './0/128.txt',
  './0/295.txt',
  './0/215.txt',
  './0/731.txt',
  './0/311.txt',
  './0/777.txt']]
```

The problem is that I can create this function if the user just enters two words each time but I don't know how to handle this if they enter more.

Comment: What's your desired output? `['./1/1129.txt']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `set` and use the intersection of each filemame lists, to get the ones that are all the lists, that allows any amount of input words

```
query = 'Dynamics Research word ok'
indexDict = {"Dynamics": ["a","b","c"], 'Research': ["a","b","g"], "other": ["j","k"]}

results = None
for word in query.split():
    if word in indexDict:
        if results is None:
            results = set(indexDict[word])
        else:
            results.intersection_update(indexDict[word])

print(results)  # {'a', 'b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one list and not a list for each word as result of your query, you could use [python sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) which guarantee duplicated items are removed.

For example:

```
list1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
list2 = [ 2, 3, 4 ]
final_list = list(set(list1 + list2))
print(final_list)
```

And this code returns: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4]`

So your code would become:

```
query = 'Dynamics Research'
queryList = query.split(" ")

finalResult = []
for word in queryList:
  found = indexDict.get(word, [])
  finalResult += found

finalResult = list(set(finalResult))
```

I also made some changes to reduce the code size by using some Python features as [dict gets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could use python sets (python3) with intersection method.
In your case you would do something like

```
result_sets = [ set(indexDict[word]) for word in queryList if word in indexDict.keys() ]
result = set.intersection(*word_sets)
```

Then you have the intersection (as a set) of the results of each word found in indexDict. (The *word_sets makes an argument list for the intersection function from the list word_sets)

You could already work with indexDict having sets instead of lists as result, then you don't need to do the conversion `set(indexDict[word])`.
If you need the result as a list, of course you can say `list(result)`.

In your case the result would be:  `{'./1/1129.txt'}`

Comment: When using only two word queries, it works perfectly but when I used a query with multiple words, it just shows ```set()```

Comment: This is then probably the empty set, i..e. the words are not contained together in any document.